# Correct typing for the first element of array

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

For typing practice purpose, I'm trying to apply the following typing to get the first element of an array :

```
type First<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [infer P, ...unknown[]] ? P : never
```

I have the following implementation :

```
const getFirstOrThrow = <T extends unknown[]>(arr: T): First<T> => {

  if(arr.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("Empty array")
  }

  return arr[0]; // Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'First<T>'.(2322)


}
```

For some reason typescript is not able to understand that the array should have at least 1 element.

I tried with the following type too :

```
type First<T extends unknown[]> = T["length"] extends 0 ? never : T[0];
type A = First<[]> // never 
type B = First<[1]> // 1 
type C = First<[1,2]> // 1
```

Is something like this possible with typescript ?

This typing seems ok to me :

```
declare function getFirst <T extends unknown[]>(arr: T): First<T>;

const A = getFirst([]) // never  
const B = getFirst([1]) // number 
const C = getFirst([1, 2]) //number
```

Comment: FWIW, I updated my answer with more alternatives. You don't need `First` for this. :-)

Comment: Yes I updated the post, this was for typescript typing practice purposes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as an alternative to [Matthieu's good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74121533/157247), a couple of other options for you (well, perhaps a couple of variations on another option):

1. You can make the type of the element generic instead of the type of the array, which avoids the need for an `extends` in the type parameter entirely:

   ```typescript
   type First<T extends unknown[]> = T["length"] extends 0 ? never : T[0];

   const getFirstOrThrow = <ElementType>(arr: ElementType[]): First<ElementType[]> => {
   // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       if (arr.length === 0) {
           throw new Error("Empty array");
       }

       return arr[0];
   };
   ```

   [Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgJwM7ADwBUoQB7AgOwBMkoBXfAa3wHsB3fAbQF0A+KAXinQYCIAbAgHNgACx5MsuAsSgAGKAH4o+CADcICKAC4uDWUwDcAKCMBjavhRRBEYPGTAA8gnQiEdDlFQBRAQFsCYHRwCBYACgBDBAQdXwgA-CCQ5gBKHXsUH39A4MhmNnY2AG8jKDKoOAAzKEjogDoBfGERDnZOWRSoEvKeqFF3WmUIQe9o6gQwnm8-MFAoKIQIkB4U4x6AXxMehFtSBHx56L1DI3XjMwsrCM8bO0QUZ1cBsN4I8VWjAHpPnoA9BQulmAUAARjdbBknC43HQXgAWABMTA+3z+APMQKgpnBdwcjxhtBe+FIfD4yOMqPK-xMgKs2BxkPxz1SFJ+VIBQA)

   I think it's fundamentally the same thing, though, since the generic type parameter is unconstrained (and thus effectively `extends any`).
2. *(This is obsoleted by your edit to the question saying you were explicitly trying to use `First`, but I'll leave it here for future readers.)* And if you use the element type as the type parameter rather than an array type, you don't need `First` anymore, you can just use `ElementType` directly (or even leave it off; it'll be inferred from the `return`):

   ```typescript
   const getFirstOrThrow = <ElementType>(arr: ElementType[]): ElementType => {
   // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^
       if (arr.length === 0) {
           throw new Error("Empty array");
       }

       return arr[0];
   };
   ```

   or (inferring from `return`):

   ```typescript
   const getFirstOrThrow = <ElementType>(arr: ElementType[]) => {
   // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
       if (arr.length === 0) {
           throw new Error("Empty array");
       }

       return arr[0];
   };
   ```

   I'd include it explicitly so that if I messed up the code inside the function, TypeScript would catch me, but I've seen it argued well both ways. :-)

   [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygMQJYCdoHl0BUAW6IA7jALwwA8AogDYIC2CYUuAngA4IB8AFAIbp0ALhh1GzVpwQBtALoBKUeKYt2XctxgBvAFAwDMVADMYAoQDp6YOFHzkyFAAwKd+wx7tFSYBKWpCIOi8AETUDBxQbDCC6PxsIQoA3O4GAL66qTDoSACu6GAxQjJOcilpKbqgkLD85PBIaJhQOATevDIh-CEANDAALABMfcb8tBAIiikA9NMeAHoA-FXg0DAARvWIKBjYeIQkHUNTurMLy9VrwFuNuy377TJgubS0J2eGS5mXsAAeNztmq0DsQOu85p9lqc5gBBV4kVA2IywKAgDYIIxgYwIIQIAAmwm+q1g2yaezaJEG9Ro9FUUi4fFiylpknUskUmjcHhMZliVmYtnsjmcrj0Hk8IJgvn8gWCYQiUSKcQSySyGSyOSg+UKsRKZV0FSJNRiVIopLuwMeXV6A2GMFG40mqo+Bi+Pw2poagPJIKOg3B5xWxuAnvNQIehyeLzezohrqh7t+odu4YpoPkscDQA)

Answer (score 1):

Make it `T extends any`:

```
const getFirstOrThrow = <T extends any[]>(arr: T): First<T> => {

  if (arr.length === 0) {
    throw new Error("Empty array")
  }

  return arr[0]; // ok
}
```

Comment: If you use `any`, you could also just do `return arr[0] as First<T>;`

Comment: I wouldn't advise to use type assertion when not necessary

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It will still throw in case the array is empty, I should've specified that I'd only change `return arr[0];` to `return arr[0] as First<T>;`. `any` just removes the need for this type assertion. (I don't like `any`, sorry :) )

Comment: @MikeS. it's not a type `any`, it's an `T extends any`.

Comment: This is for practice purpose, is there any way it can work without the any ?

Comment: @MikeS. - Gotcha. But as Matthieu says, it's not actually using `any` as a type, just as the basis of a generic that can be anything. To me, it's absolutely fine in this sort of situation, the actual type will be inferred ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJXxZN)). But I did come up with an alternative that avoids explicit mention of `any` and avoid type assertions (see my answer), though I think the `any` is fundamentally implied in it. :-)